# PHP - switch statement, without breaks in every case

Tags: php

This has got me stumped for a while now...
I was taught switch statements in PHP only use the "break" keyword in order to break the circuit of the switch statement.
Instead of using multiple if statements, to keep things clean, I used a switch statement (to validate a username/password)
This is the code.

Code:

```
    switch(true){

    case($passwords[$key] != $password):
        echo "The username and/or password is incorrect<br>";
    case(strlen($username) < 4 || strlen($username) > 10):
        echo "The username must be between 4-10 characters<br>";
    case(strlen($password) < 4):
        echo "The password must be at least 4 characters<br>";            
    case(1>2):
        echo $username . " " . $password . " " . strlen($username) . " " . strlen($password);
        break;

    default:
        echo "Login Success<br>";
}
```

If I inputted:
Username: Kyle
Password: foobar

I would expect ONLY the output "The username and/or password is incorrect
" as this is the only true condition...
However, everything up until break seems to evaluate as true, outputting everything but the default, even though (1>2) is clearly false...

Help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Why are you running a switch when you can just use conditions... `if { } else { }`

Comment: Once a case is evaluated as true, every statement below is processed until it finds a break or the switch ends.

Comment: Being a C person - does this run without warnings? Multiple of the case switches will resolve with the same true/false value

Comment: This case is clearly explained in the examples on http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Why would you `switch(true)`? If you want something to happen then put it in a method or function. This looks like bad logic. Rethink what you are trying to achieve as you should be able to do this in a more readable and logical way, as others have suggested here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Each of the used case blocks should end with a break. Otherwise, the code will execute the next case and so on, making use of what's called as fall-through.
This feature can be useful in some scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add a break in every case:

```
case($passwords[$key] != $password):
        echo "The username and/or password is incorrect<br>";
        break;
    case(strlen($username) < 4 || strlen($username) > 10):
        echo "The username must be between 4-10 characters<br>";
        break;
    case(strlen($password) < 4):
        echo "The password must be at least 4 characters<br>";
        break;            
    case(1>2):
        echo $username . " " . $password . " " . strlen($username) . " " . strlen($password);
        break;
```

Comment: @kyleBlue Why ou anexcept my answer and accept an answer with is worse?

Answer (score -1):

If you wish to use a `case` statement then each `case` should include a break. In your example code since its not really that lengthy this could be easily accomplished with an `if..else..` statement and would be acceptable.